# Jekyll Links is not properly working

Tags: hyperlink, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

github site: https://geloangelia.github.io/mynewsite/profile

REPO: https://github.com/geloangelia/mynewsite

I am having trouble with the links. i doesn't link to the right path.
the path should be _site\vclist(NAME)

CODE:

```
<ul>
{% for list in site.data.vclist %}
  <li><a href="{{ list.Name | datapage_url: 'vclist'}}">{{list.Name}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code in the question so it can be understood without going to external sites (beside that having the github repo is helpful sometimes)

Comment: hi marcanuy description edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you generate the links with the filter tag, you need to add the basepath to the generated URLs and specify the directory where the plugin generates the files:

```
<ul>
{% for list in site.data.vclist %}
  <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}/{{ list.Name | datapage_url: '/vclist' }}">{{list.Name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Also, the permalink shouldn't be located in the layout, so remove the permalink from `_layouts/profile.html`

```
 ---
 layout: page
 ---
```

Comment: I follow this, unfortunately, Im getting the same error : 404 File not found

Comment: code: <ul>
{% for list in site.data.vclist %}
  <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}/{{ list.Name | datapage_url: '/vclist' }}">{{list.Name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

Comment: I've tested locally and works fine, the build can take a few minutes as the data file is big, also you can post the error if there is any https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-jekyll-build-error-messages/

Comment: Actually, its working too when I run it locally, but after I uploaded it on github, its getting broken links error.

Comment: Github pages has a restricted set of plugins, the plugin you are using won't work there, unless you upload the built site it won't work.